# What does Grails do with the database and dataSource during deployment?

Tags: grails

It seems that Grails is trying to access my database when I first deploy it to my production tomcat server.  I know this because I get the following error message in the stacktrace.log

```
invalid username/password; login denied
```

Now, I disabled database creation

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    //Set jdbc metadata to false to not open a session
    temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "none"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:xe"
    }
}
```

I don't supply the database password because we use database users for authentication and authorization (please don't criticize this decision, I know it's awful, but we have a legacy database).  So the username/password is supplied when the user makes a request through the client.  We used http://sergiosmind.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/grails-using-a-database-user-for-security-login/ to set this up.

It seems that the Grails app cannot start because of this.  Why is Grails accessing the database?  What is it trying to do?

Comment: the dbCreate parameter is trying to set how Grails handles updating/creating/dropping schema changes to your Domain classes. That's why it's trying to access the database. Setting it to "none" tells Grails not to try and manage this during app startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails uses connections at startup to initialize GORM - there's one to detect the dialect, one to configure the LOB handler, and Hibernate connects to initialize its configuration also.

I discuss this in these two blog posts: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=312 and http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1565

Comment: Fantastic!! I actually had already done this, so I'm not sure why Grails was accessing the database on deploy.  Could it be that existing connections during a redeploy cause some kind of database access?  I got the same suggestions you made from a different blog.  It's the blog link in my question to sergiosmind.

Comment: Do you have the pool configured to periodically check connection validity?

Comment: I'm not using a connection pool.  Is it still possible that existing connections are checked for validity?

Comment: I've expanded the question to contain all the config lines relating to production, so you can see pooling is disabled.

Comment: Why would you ever disable pooling? This is crazy. The cost of creating a new connection each time is pretty significant. The only time you want to disable pooling is when you're using a JNDI datasource that is pooling, so creating a local pool doesn't help anything.

Comment: Lol!  Yes, I must be crazy.  I appreciate your help Burt, but it is not crazy.  See Sergio's blog that I link in the question.  I have a legacy database and there's costs to switch the user authentication and authorization.  Please don't question it unless you would like to analyze the costs with me.  I am also open to alternative approaches to database user auth from the approach Sergio gives.  I've spent countless hours trying to switch this... we will eventually move away from database auth, but it's there for now.

Comment: I also would like to mention that this approach (without connection pooling) is several orders of magnitude faster than the previous developer's approach (which didn't use REST at all).  So my client is very happy and we don't need to worry about connection pooling at the moment.  But you are correct that disabling connection pooling has severe costs on performance and we will address those down the road.